# Object creation via for loop in MS Edge fails

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

we are facing a strange issue with the MS Edge browser which happens on some environments more often and on some never.

```
var myObject = {};
var someNumber = 8;
for (var i = -someNumber; i <= someNumber; i++) {
    myObject[i] = {};
}
```

We obviously expect an object in the end containing elements called -8, -7, -6, ... till 8. This is then later on filled with data. But in Edge it happens sometimes, that the variable myObject is just containing "8" as element after this loop. All the other values are not existing. Did anyone experience something similar?

We tried to assign directly some value also to the generated elements, but that also had no effect.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in for loop handling of Edge. I realized, that this is no more happening when I do not use negative numbers in the loop and just start at 0.

```
var myObject = {};
var someNumber = 8;
for (var i = 0; i <= 2 * someNumber; i++) {
    myObject[i - someNumber] = {};
}
```